# Multi-Page Progressbar Sveltekit & TailwindCSS

Tags: progress-bar, tailwind-css, sveltekit

I am relatively new to Svelte-kit and I am trying to create a "Progress-bar" Component, which tracks the progress of the user (How far he is in the registration progress).

How the Process should run: As a user, I click through the process and after every step, a new component gets loaded and the progress bar should be uploaded.

My ProgressBar.svelte Component:

```html
<script>
export let progress;

if (progress === undefined){
    progress = 0;
}

</script>

<div class="w-full bg-gray-200">
    <div class="bg-red-600 text-xs font-medium text-blue-100 text-center p-1 leading-none" style="width: {progress}%"> {progress}%</div>
</div>
```

As for the form the user has to go through, I have a +layout.svelte component:

```html
<script>
    import ProgressBar from '.ProgressBar.svelte';
    export let progress = 0;
</script>


<ProgressBar {progress}/>
<main class="container mx-auto min-h-screen max-w-screen-sm px-4 pt-10">
    <div class="mt-8">
        <slot />
    </div>
</main>
```

The `<slot />` component renders the forms necessary for the registration.

In total there are 8 steps the user has to go through, which means that every step, everytime the slot changes, the progress bar should go up 12.5%.

Thank you for your help and if you need anything else, I will try to provide it! :)

I already tried to manipulate the "progress" variable in the form-pages but sadly without any luck. I still don't quite understand the data forwarding from parent to child and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a context in the layout that then can be used in the steps:

```js
import { setContext } from 'svelte';
// ...

let progress = 0;

setContext('progress', {
    next() {
        progress += 0.125;

        // [navigate to next step]
    }
});
```

In steps:

```html
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';

    const progressContext = getContext('progress');
</script>

<!-- ... -->

<button on:click={() => progressContext.next()}>
    Next
</button>
```

(Of course it might also make sense to add navigation buttons directly to the layout instead and use some conditionals to enable/disable them or change their labels.)

---

If you want to change the value directly, you can create a store and pass that through the context:

```js
import { setContext } from 'svelte';
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
// ...

let progress = writable(0);
    
setContext('progress', progress);
```

```html
<ProgressBar progress={$progress} />
```

In step:

```html
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';

    const progress = getContext('progress');
    const onClick = () => { $progress += 0.125; ... };
</script>

<button on:click={onClick}>Next</button>
```

Comment: Hi H.B, thank you for your answer! Isn't there any way that I can change the "progress" variable from another component? I find it hard to explain, but is it possible to manipulate the variable through 2 exports? (i.e I export the variable from ProgressBar.svelte and export it again from +layout.svelte so that I can change it in other components).

Comment: If you want to manipulate it directly, you have to 1. make it a `writable` store, 2. add it to the context so it gets passed down.